# Android cannot get TextViews to display with LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, text, layout, view

I am simply trying to create a layout where there are multiple TextViews (and ultimately an EditText) stacked vertically in the activity. However, the only thing displayed is my top title bar and the first TextView (with the "Name" text). Why won't anything else show up? Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView android:text="Name:" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:textColor="#4096cc"
        android:paddingTop="15dip" android:paddingLeft="15dip"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="This is my little description."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#333333" android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="15dip" android:textSize="10sp" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `layout_height` for the TextView needs to be `wrap_content`, not `fill_parent`.

Comment: Sure thing! Layouts can be tricky. But you'll get used to them!